# changed ISP (Starlink) now some websites unreachable?

Tags: networking, server, firefox, google-chrome, internet

I have moved to a new job which has Starlink ISP. Since connected to this, chrome, Firefox will not show many websites. For example I can not view BBC.com it is unreachable, but I can view Google and search for BBC or CNN. But those sites(BBC, CNN) will not load are unreachable. Ask Ubuntu is unreachable. But YouTube will load and play videos. Anyone help me with step by step help?